# Hartl's rails tutorial completed works locally perfect. Heroku persists "We're sorry, but something went wrong."

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, railstutorial.org

I'm new to Ruby on Rails (new to programming altogether) and this is my first post on stack overflow. I want to thank everyone in advance because I have learned so much from previous posts.

I completed the Micheal Hartl Ruby on Rails Tutorial but can't get it to launch successfully on Heroku even though it works perfect locally.

Iv done the following:

> git push
>
> git push heroku master
>
> heroku pg:reset DATABASE
>
> heroku run rake db:migrate
>
> heroku run rake db:populate

(I have also done this without heroku restart with same results)

Things go wrong when I preform command: heroku run rake db:populate

Here is my heroku log

```
2013-04-23T18:27:42.388610+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R12 (Exit timeout) -> At least one process failed to exit within 10 seconds of SIGTERM
2013-04-23T18:27:42.388610+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping remaining processes with SIGKILL
2013-04-23T18:27:44.355310+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2013-04-23T18:27:50.065370+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by SessionsController#new as HTML
2013-04-23T18:27:50.062379+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/signin" for 75.68.91.34 at 2013-04-23 18:27:50 +0000
2013-04-23T18:27:50.091947+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (24.8ms)
2013-04-23T18:27:50.093017+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.0ms)
2013-04-23T18:27:50.095496+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (2.2ms)
2013-04-23T18:27:50.096137+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 31ms (Views: 29.2ms | ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)
2013-04-23T18:27:50.095966+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.3ms)
2013-04-23T18:27:50.102068+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/signin host=polar-wildwood-1990.herokuapp.com fwd="75.68.91.34" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=48ms status=200 bytes=2144
2013-04-23T18:27:52.271911+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/help" for 75.68.91.34 at 2013-04-23 18:27:52 +0000
2013-04-23T18:27:52.275101+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by StaticPagesController#help as HTML
2013-04-23T18:27:52.276587+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered static_pages/help.html.erb within layouts/application (0.3ms)
2013-04-23T18:27:52.277601+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.0ms)
2013-04-23T18:27:52.281995+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (4.1ms)
2013-04-23T18:27:52.283227+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.8ms)
2013-04-23T18:27:52.284385+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 9ms (Views: 7.2ms | ActiveRecord: 1.4ms)
2013-04-23T18:27:52.291644+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/help host=polar-wildwood-1990.herokuapp.com fwd="75.68.91.34" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=21ms status=200 bytes=1639
2013-04-23T18:27:53.244364+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=polar-wildwood-1990.herokuapp.com fwd="75.68.91.34" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=18ms status=304 bytes=0
2013-04-23T18:27:53.227078+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 75.68.91.34 at 2013-04-23 18:27:53 +0000
2013-04-23T18:27:53.230685+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by StaticPagesController#home as HTML
2013-04-23T18:27:53.233227+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered static_pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (0.6ms)
2013-04-23T18:27:53.234925+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (0.8ms)
2013-04-23T18:27:53.234029+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.0ms)
2013-04-23T18:27:53.235301+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.3ms)
2013-04-23T18:27:53.235416+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 5ms (Views: 3.2ms | ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)
2013-04-23T18:27:54.503953+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/signin" for 75.68.91.34 at 2013-04-23 18:27:54 +0000
2013-04-23T18:27:54.506797+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by SessionsController#new as HTML
2013-04-23T18:27:54.509530+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.0ms)
2013-04-23T18:27:54.508584+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (1.3ms)
2013-04-23T18:27:54.511848+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (2.1ms)
2013-04-23T18:27:54.512476+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.3ms)
2013-04-23T18:27:54.512701+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 6ms (Views: 4.7ms | ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)
2013-04-23T18:27:54.522049+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/signin host=polar-wildwood-1990.herokuapp.com fwd="75.68.91.34" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=16ms status=304 bytes=0
2013-04-23T18:28:02.210398+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 75.68.91.34 at 2013-04-23 18:28:02 +0000
2013-04-23T18:28:02.212290+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by StaticPagesController#home as HTML
2013-04-23T18:28:02.214616+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered static_pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (0.6ms)
2013-04-23T18:28:02.215472+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.0ms)
2013-04-23T18:28:02.216369+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (0.8ms)
2013-04-23T18:28:02.216867+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 5ms (Views: 3.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.9ms)
2013-04-23T18:28:02.216742+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.3ms)
2013-04-23T18:28:02.224795+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=polar-wildwood-1990.herokuapp.com fwd="75.68.91.34" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=15ms status=304 bytes=0
2013-04-23T18:28:03.312964+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/signup" for 75.68.91.34 at 2013-04-23 18:28:03 +0000
2013-04-23T18:28:03.320889+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by UsersController#new as HTML
2013-04-23T18:28:03.330931+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered shared/_error_messages.html.erb (0.3ms)
2013-04-23T18:28:03.332690+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered users/new.html.erb within layouts/application (4.5ms)
2013-04-23T18:28:03.333486+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.0ms)
2013-04-23T18:28:03.335702+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (2.1ms)
2013-04-23T18:28:03.336140+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.3ms)
2013-04-23T18:28:03.336258+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 15ms (Views: 8.2ms | ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)
2013-04-23T18:28:03.343166+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/signup host=polar-wildwood-1990.herokuapp.com fwd="75.68.91.34" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=31ms status=200 bytes=2403
2013-04-23T18:28:23.175897+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by UsersController#create as HTML
2013-04-23T18:28:23.172784+00:00 app[web.1]: Started POST "/users" for 75.68.91.34 at 2013-04-23 18:28:23 +0000
2013-04-23T18:28:23.175897+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"rdA4wrQvQhEhejI6uTXYg2YZpa5sl7gkYeabVJZQmFA=", "user"=>{"name"=>"Dana Bouchard", "email"=>"dbouchard138@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Create my account"}
2013-04-23T18:28:23.429861+00:00 app[web.1]: Redirected to https://polar-wildwood-1990.herokuapp.com/users/1
2013-04-23T18:28:23.433167+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 302 Found in 256ms (ActiveRecord: 21.6ms)
2013-04-23T18:28:23.449918+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path=/users host=polar-wildwood-1990.herokuapp.com fwd="75.68.91.34" dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=315ms status=302 bytes=115
2013-04-23T18:28:23.497155+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
2013-04-23T18:28:23.490244+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/users/1" for 75.68.91.34 at 2013-04-23 18:28:23 +0000
2013-04-23T18:28:23.496980+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by UsersController#show as HTML
2013-04-23T18:28:23.722402+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered shared/_stats.html.erb (54.1ms)
2013-04-23T18:28:23.787319+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered users/show.html.erb within layouts/application (120.1ms)
2013-04-23T18:28:23.787319+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 290ms
2013-04-23T18:28:23.789034+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (PGError: ERROR:  relation "microposts" does not exist
2013-04-23T18:28:23.789034+00:00 app[web.1]:
2013-04-23T18:28:23.789034+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 5:              WHERE a.attrelid = '"microposts"'::regclass
2013-04-23T18:28:23.789034+00:00 app[web.1]:                                         ^
2013-04-23T18:28:23.789034+00:00 app[web.1]: :             SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
2013-04-23T18:28:23.789034+00:00 app[web.1]:                      pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod
2013-04-23T18:28:23.789034+00:00 app[web.1]:               FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
2013-04-23T18:28:23.789034+00:00 app[web.1]:                 ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
2013-04-23T18:28:23.789034+00:00 app[web.1]:
 WHERE a.attrelid = '"microposts"'::regclass
2013-04-23T18:28:23.789293+00:00 app[web.1]: ):
2013-04-23T18:28:23.789293+00:00 app[web.1]:              ORDER BY a.attnum
2013-04-23T18:28:23.789293+00:00 app[web.1]:     15:     <%= render 'follow_form' if signed_in? %>
2013-04-23T18:28:23.789034+00:00 app[web.1]:                AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
2013-04-23T18:28:23.789293+00:00 app[web.1]:     13:   </aside>
2013-04-23T18:28:23.789293+00:00 app[web.1]:     14:   <div class="span8">
2013-04-23T18:28:23.800620+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/users/1 host=polar-wildwood-1990.herokuapp.com fwd="75.68.91.34" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=313ms status=500 bytes=643
2013-04-23T18:28:23.789293+00:00 app[web.1]:     16:     <% if @user.microposts.any? %>
2013-04-23T18:28:23.789293+00:00 app[web.1]:     17:       <h3>Microposts (<%= @user.microposts.count %>)</h3>
2013-04-23T18:28:23.789293+00:00 app[web.1]:     18:       <ol class="microposts">
2013-04-23T18:28:23.789293+00:00 app[web.1]:     19:         <%= render @microposts %>
2013-04-23T18:28:23.789293+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/users/show.html.erb:16:in `_app_views_users_show_html_erb__4534392174835113617_69860797342160'
2013-04-23T18:28:23.789517+00:00 app[web.1]:
2013-04-23T18:28:23.789517+00:00 app[web.1]:
2013-04-23T18:28:38.118917+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:populate` by dbouchard138@gmail.com
2013-04-23T18:28:40.122057+00:00 heroku[run.9072]: Awaiting client
2013-04-23T18:28:40.141935+00:00 heroku[run.9072]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:populate`
2013-04-23T18:28:41.013463+00:00 heroku[run.9072]: State changed from starting to up
2013-04-23T18:29:06.377140+00:00 heroku[run.9072]: Process exited with status 1
2013-04-23T18:29:06.395386+00:00 heroku[run.9072]: State changed from up to complete
2013-04-23T19:31:08.418618+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
2013-04-23T19:31:11.275801+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2013-04-23T19:31:12.010696+00:00 app[web.1]:    /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:90:in `select'
2013-04-23T19:31:12.010696+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-04-23 19:31:12] ERROR SignalException: SIGTERM
2013-04-23T19:31:22.107373+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R12 (Exit timeout) -> At least one process failed to exit within 10 seconds of SIGTERM
2013-04-23T19:31:22.107928+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping remaining processes with SIGKILL
2013-04-23T19:31:23.892161+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
2013-04-23T19:31:23.878809+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
```

This is probaly as easy fix, I assume the below is the culpret but I can't figure out why or how to locate the issue.

```
2013-04-23T18:28:23.789034+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (PGError: ERROR:  relation "microposts" does not exist
2013-04-23T18:28:23.789034+00:00 app[web.1]:
2013-04-23T18:28:23.789034+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 5:              WHERE a.attrelid = '"microposts"'::regclass
2013-04-23T18:28:23.789034+00:00 app[web.1]:                                         ^
2013-04-23T18:28:23.789034+00:00 app[web.1]: :             SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
2013-04-23T18:28:23.789034+00:00 app[web.1]:                      pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod
2013-04-23T18:28:23.789034+00:00 app[web.1]:               FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
2013-04-23T18:28:23.789034+00:00 app[web.1]:                 ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
2013-04-23T18:28:23.789034+00:00 app[web.1]:
 WHERE a.attrelid = '"microposts"'::regclass
2013-04-23T18:28:23.789293+00:00 app[web.1]: ):
2013-04-23T18:28:23.789293+00:00 app[web.1]:              ORDER BY a.attnum
2013-04-23T18:28:23.789293+00:00 app[web.1]:     15:     <%= render 'follow_form' if signed_in? %>
2013-04-23T18:28:23.789034+00:00 app[web.1]:                AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
2013-04-23T18:28:23.789293+00:00 app[web.1]:     13:   </aside>
2013-04-23T18:28:23.789293+00:00 app[web.1]:     14:   <div class="span8">
2013-04-23T18:28:23.800620+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/users/1 host=polar-wildwood-1990.herokuapp.com fwd="75.68.91.34" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=313ms status=500 bytes=643
2013-04-23T18:28:23.789293+00:00 app[web.1]:     16:     <% if @user.microposts.any? %>
2013-04-23T18:28:23.789293+00:00 app[web.1]:     17:       <h3>Microposts (<%= @user.microposts.count %>)</h3>
2013-04-23T18:28:23.789293+00:00 app[web.1]:     18:       <ol class="microposts">
2013-04-23T18:28:23.789293+00:00 app[web.1]:     19:         <%= render @microposts %>
2013-04-23T18:28:23.789293+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/users/show.html.erb:16:in `_app_views_users_show_html_erb__4534392174835113617_69860797342160'
```

Please help, if you need any more information let me know.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you double check with `git status` that all the relevant files are actually committed?

Comment: You might find adding `$stdout.sync = true` to the top of your `config.ru` makes your logs easier to understand – they seem to be out of order.

Comment: forgive me is this is a ridiculous question but would I include that $ sign if I just placed the code into the file?

Comment: @DanaBouchard yes, you need the `$`. It’s to call [`sync=true`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/IO.html#method-i-sync-3D) on the standard output, which is the global variable `$stdout`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds to me like you didn't load the schema into your heroku database.  After deploying what happens when you do this:

```
heroku run rake db:schema:load
```

Note that sometimes if you're loading up a new app that has an already-established schema, running all the migrations isn't the best way to get the database to the state you want - you should use `rake db:schema:load` instead.  Let me know if this gets your database correct.

After running it you can use `heroku run console` and then do console commands like `User.all` to make sure it knows that the `users` table exists etc.

Don't forget to restart your server after loading the schema, or running `db:migrate`. For heroku that'd be: `heroku restart`

Comment: What does this bring to the table (over db:migrate)?

Comment: `db:migrate` becomes more and more brittle the more migrations you end up having.  For an initial database setup `schema:load` is what you should use which will set the database up to what is defined in `db/schema.rb`.  If the database is already established then of course  you're going to want to be using `db:migrate` because anything else is going to destroy the data you have in the database.  You can also use `rake db:setup` which will load the schema and initialize the DB with any seed data you setup.

Comment: Thank you so much This fixed the issue! Im so glad I decided to post the question. I have struggled through so many silly issues like this figuring I would not get a fast of accurate response (mainly because I didn't think I could pose the question is a way that makes logical sense to "real" programers.) I will be using Stackoverflow far more often thanks nzifnab

Comment: Thank you @nzifnab your answer solved my problem. I was struggling to upload Toy_App on heroku which was totally working fine on localhost:3000.