# railstutorial.org signup mechanism fails on the deployed app via Heroku

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, railstutorial.org

I've been going through the aforementioned tutorial step-by-step, and currently finished chapter 11.
When trying to sign-up on the deployed app `https://nameless-depths-7391.herokuapp.com`, in the **production** environment, I constantly encounter failures to do so:

> We're sorry, but something went wrong.
>   If you are the application owner check the logs for more information.

When I switch the app to the **development** environment, just as expected, a `flash` is rendered that states I should wait for a confirmation email, but it never arrives.
Furthermore, when I run the test suite like so:

`$ heroku run rake test`

It is RED, with:
`52 runs, 146 assertions, 11 failures, 7 errors, 0 skips` (exact output at the end of the post)

BUT, when I run the test suite locally like so:

`$ bundle exec rake test`

the test suite is GREEN:

`/Users/asafchelouche/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/fog-1.23.0/lib/fog/rackspace/mock_data.rb:42: warning: duplicated key at line 80 ignored: "name"
Run options: --seed 23184
Running:
....................................................
Finished in 1.676356s, 31.0197 runs/s, 169.4151 assertions/s.
52 runs, 284 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips`

AFAIK I've carefully executed all steps that relate to the app's deployment to Heroku.
I tried to reset the app's db:

`$ heroku run rake db:migrate:reset`

`$ heroku run rake db:migrate`

but it doesn't do any good. Also, I tried `$ heroku run rake bd:schema:load` as found in the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16178416/hartls-rails-tutorial-completed-works-locally-perfect-heroku-persists-were-s) question, but to no avail.

My implementation: `https://github.com/asafch/sample_rails_app`

**NOTE**: when going over all of the test suite's error messages, I see that tests that go all the way back to chapter 8 (login\logout) are failing, which is very odd.

**The test suite output on Heroku**:

```
Running `rake test` attached to terminal... up, run.8084
Run options: --seed 23930
Running:
.....F....................F.FFF.EEEF.FF..FFF.EE...EE
Finished in 44.660405s, 1.1643 runs/s, 3.2691 assertions/s.
1) Failure:
MicropostsInterfaceTest#test_micropost_interface         [/app/test/integration/microposts_interface_test.rb:12]:
Expected at least 1 element matching "div.pagination", found 0..
Expected 0 to be >= 1.
2) Failure:
UsersIndexTest#test_index_as_admin_including_pagination_and_delete_links     [/app/test/integration/users_index_test.rb:13]:
expecting <"users/index"> but rendering with <[]>
3) Failure:
UsersLoginTest#test_login_with_remembering [/app/test/integration/users_login_test.rb:43]:
Expected nil to not be nil.
4) Failure:
UsersLoginTest#test_login_with_valid_information [/app/test/integration/users_login_test.rb:12]:
Expected response to be a <redirect>, but was <422>
5) Failure:
UsersLoginTest#test_login_with_valid_information_followed_by_logout [/app/test/integration/users_login_test.rb:23]:
Failed assertion, no message given.
 6) Error:
MicropostsControllerTest#test_should_redirect_create_when_not_logged_in:
ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken: ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken
test/controllers/microposts_controller_test.rb:11:in `block (2 levels) in <class:MicropostsControllerTest>'
test/controllers/microposts_controller_test.rb:10:in `block in <class:MicropostsControllerTest>'
7) Error:
MicropostsControllerTest#test_should_redirect_destroy_for_wrong_micropost:
ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken: ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken
test/controllers/microposts_controller_test.rb:27:in `block (2 levels) in <class:MicropostsControllerTest>'
test/controllers/microposts_controller_test.rb:26:in `block in <class:MicropostsControllerTest>'
8) Error:
MicropostsControllerTest#test_should_redirect_destroy_when_not_logged_in:
ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken: ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken
test/controllers/microposts_controller_test.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in <class:MicropostsControllerTest>'
test/controllers/microposts_controller_test.rb:17:in `block in <class:MicropostsControllerTest>'
9) Failure:
PasswordResetsTest#test_password_resets [/app/test/integration/password_resets_test.rb:14]:
Expected true to be nil or false
10) Failure:
UsersSignupTest#test_invalid_signup_information [/app/test/integration/users_signup_test.rb:17]:
expecting <"users/new"> but rendering with <["rescues/_source", "rescues/_trace", "rescues/_request_and_response", "rescues/diagnostics", "rescues/layout"]>
11) Failure:
UsersSignupTest#test_valid_signup_information_with_account_activation [/app/test/integration/users_signup_test.rb:24]:
"User.count" didn't change by 1.
Expected: 35
Actual: 34
12) Failure:
UsersEditTest#test_successful_edit [/app/test/integration/users_edit_test.rb:23]:
expecting <"users/edit"> but rendering with <[]>
13) Failure:
UsersEditTest#test_successful_edit_with_friendly_forwarding [/app/test/integration/users_edit_test.rb:40]:
Expected response to be a <redirect>, but was <422>
14) Failure:
UsersEditTest#test_unsuccessful_edit [/app/test/integration/users_edit_test.rb:12]:
expecting <"users/edit"> but rendering with <[]>
15) Error:
UsersControllerTest#test_should_redirect_destroy_when_logged_in_as_a_non-admin:
ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken: ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken
test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb:56:in `block (2 levels) in <class:UsersControllerTest>'
test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb:55:in `block in <class:UsersControllerTest>'
16) Error:
UsersControllerTest#test_should_redirect_destroy_when_not_logged_in:
ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken: ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken
test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb:48:in `block (2 levels) in <class:UsersControllerTest>'
test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb:47:in `block in <class:UsersControllerTest>'
17) Error:
UsersControllerTest#test_should_redirect_update_when_logged_in_as_wrong_user:
ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken: ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken
test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb:41:in `block in <class:UsersControllerTest>'
18) Error:
UsersControllerTest#test_should_redirect_update_when_not_logged_in:
ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken: ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken
test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb:27:in `block in <class:UsersControllerTest>'
52 runs, 146 assertions, 11 failures, 7 errors, 0 skips
```

**Heroku's log**:

```
2015-08-29T12:36:58.099794+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (0.3ms)
2015-08-29T12:36:58.097169+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by StaticPagesController#home as HTML
2015-08-29T12:36:58.099420+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.1ms)
2015-08-29T12:36:58.100108+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.1ms)
2015-08-29T12:36:58.603816+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/application-fabce92ad63641b6fba3541208baa5fa6f9123fbc2a6ff53755cfa33c82906f3.css" host=nameless-depths-7391.herokuapp.com request_id=c8ea3d98-cf7a-4dd9-b4b0-da0fb51ef1b5 fwd="79.176.4.149" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=3ms status=304 bytes=74
2015-08-29T12:36:58.922093+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/application-f26e3b60020a4a03b7dd1f85013a27fd2f7f7e11c4e044cd603969a46ab6935a.js" host=nameless-depths-7391.herokuapp.com request_id=6fff861f-80a0-4107-97cf-69e05c1b4015 fwd="79.176.4.149" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=3ms status=304 bytes=74
2015-08-29T12:37:15.016822+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/signup" host=nameless-depths-7391.herokuapp.com request_id=ce618a5a-163c-4769-9c7c-e7278bfb5cd1 fwd="79.176.4.149" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=10ms status=200 bytes=3455
2015-08-29T12:37:15.005503+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/signup" for 79.176.4.149 at 2015-08-29 12:37:15 +0000
2015-08-29T12:37:15.009679+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered shared/_error_messages.html.erb (0.1ms)
2015-08-29T12:37:15.012161+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.0ms)
2015-08-29T12:37:15.012849+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.1ms)
2015-08-29T12:37:15.007821+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by UsersController#new as HTML
2015-08-29T12:37:15.011589+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered users/new.html.erb within layouts/application (2.5ms)
2015-08-29T12:37:15.012538+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (0.3ms)
2015-08-29T12:37:15.013038+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 5ms (Views: 4.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
2015-08-29T12:37:30.022268+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=nameless-depths-7391.herokuapp.com request_id=2d58c784-34bc-446a-8581-bb4aa88f03ec fwd="182.118.26.137" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=20ms status=200 bytes=2825
2015-08-29T12:37:30.003013+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 182.118.26.137 at 2015-08-29 12:37:30 +0000
2015-08-29T12:37:30.010693+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered static_pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (1.1ms)
2015-08-29T12:37:30.017831+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (1.0ms)
2015-08-29T12:37:30.021281+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 15ms (Views: 14.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
2015-08-29T12:37:30.005831+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by StaticPagesController#home as */*
2015-08-29T12:37:30.014298+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.3ms)
2015-08-29T12:37:30.020946+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.5ms)
2015-08-29T12:37:31.491695+00:00 app[web.1]: Started POST "/users" for 79.176.4.149 at 2015-08-29 12:37:31 +0000
2015-08-29T12:37:31.615642+00:00 app[web.1]:   User Exists (1.4ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE LOWER("users"."email") = LOWER('asaf.chelouche@gmail.com') LIMIT 1
2015-08-29T12:37:31.494061+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by UsersController#create as HTML
2015-08-29T12:37:31.494120+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"xiISJ8y3tgq8uBzbd05EJDurGpKQiinQYIwEF1ZNv//hD9/s+etKeWTnyAQXLY8HjJepW0OgHK2iMNys+OtdBw==", "user"=>{"name"=>"asaf ch", "email"=>"asaf.chelouche@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Create my account"}
2015-08-29T12:37:31.612625+00:00 app[web.1]:    (1.2ms)  BEGIN
2015-08-29T12:37:31.981951+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=nameless-depths-7391.herokuapp.com request_id=a4766c79-3da5-4d1b-8458-8f97ebe8ae60 fwd="182.118.44.84" dyno=web.1 connect=16ms service=21ms status=200 bytes=2825
2015-08-29T12:37:31.808987+00:00 app[web.1]:   SQL (1.3ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("name", "email", "password_digest", "created_at", "updated_at", "activation_digest") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6) RETURNING "id"  [["name", "asaf ch"], ["email", "asaf.chelouche@gmail.com"], ["password_digest", "$2a$10$nzvHYiJOXbfFjeHbn2SsA.1Zjhn.x2xg4NZWMAqc.dBRBNDImw2di"], ["created_at", "2015-08-29 12:37:31.615996"], ["updated_at", "2015-08-29 12:37:31.615996"], ["activation_digest", "$2a$10$3eqLiSag9r2i7jo24imUQuGds1ODiVGb4UdicnpzfMqQBk9cRbikm"]]
2015-08-29T12:37:31.813557+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered user_mailer/account_activation.html.erb within layouts/mailer (0.5ms)
2015-08-29T12:37:31.821608+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-08-29T12:37:31.821612+00:00 app[web.1]: UserMailer#account_activation: processed outbound mail in 9.3ms
2015-08-29T12:37:31.859292+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-08-29T12:37:31.859297+00:00 app[web.1]: Sent mail to asaf.chelouche@gmail.com (37.5ms)
2015-08-29T12:37:31.859304+00:00 app[web.1]: Date: Sat, 29 Aug 2015 12:37:31 +0000
2015-08-29T12:37:31.859305+00:00 app[web.1]: From: noreply@example.com
2015-08-29T12:37:31.859306+00:00 app[web.1]: To: asaf.chelouche@gmail.com
2015-08-29T12:37:31.859309+00:00 app[web.1]: Subject: Account activation
2015-08-29T12:37:31.859308+00:00 app[web.1]: Message-ID: <55e1a78bc9e7c_d3ff9ffe09e88587bf@08cdc2e4-7c1e-49a8-95bd-7f4c5df6058e.mail>
2015-08-29T12:37:31.859311+00:00 app[web.1]: Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
2015-08-29T12:37:31.859313+00:00 app[web.1]:  boundary="--==_mimepart_55e1a78bc83df_d3ff9ffe09e8858677";
2015-08-29T12:37:31.859310+00:00 app[web.1]: Mime-Version: 1.0
2015-08-29T12:37:31.859314+00:00 app[web.1]:  charset=UTF-8
2015-08-29T12:37:31.859315+00:00 app[web.1]: Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
2015-08-29T12:37:31.859316+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-08-29T12:37:31.859318+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-08-29T12:37:31.859321+00:00 app[web.1]: Content-Type: text/plain;
2015-08-29T12:37:31.859320+00:00 app[web.1]: ----==_mimepart_55e1a78bc83df_d3ff9ffe09e8858677
2015-08-29T12:37:31.859323+00:00 app[web.1]:  charset=UTF-8
2015-08-29T12:37:31.859324+00:00 app[web.1]: Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
2015-08-29T12:37:31.859326+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-08-29T12:37:31.859327+00:00 app[web.1]: Hi asaf ch,
2015-08-29T12:37:31.859329+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-08-29T12:37:31.811699+00:00 app[web.1]:    (2.1ms)  COMMIT
2015-08-29T12:37:31.859330+00:00 app[web.1]: Welcome to the Sample App! Click on the link below to activate your account:
2015-08-29T12:37:31.813983+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered user_mailer/account_activation.text.erb within layouts/mailer (0.2ms)
2015-08-29T12:37:31.859332+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-08-29T12:37:31.966486+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by StaticPagesController#home as HTML
2015-08-29T12:37:31.859333+00:00 app[web.1]: http://nameless-depths-7391.herokuapp.com/account_activations/puYr8iDaYEhA7AVzZFccQw/edit?email=asaf.chelouche%40gmail.com
2015-08-29T12:37:31.971310+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.4ms)
2015-08-29T12:37:31.859335+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-08-29T12:37:31.859336+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-08-29T12:37:31.973214+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (1.3ms)
2015-08-29T12:37:31.859337+00:00 app[web.1]: ----==_mimepart_55e1a78bc83df_d3ff9ffe09e8858677
2015-08-29T12:37:31.974958+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.9ms)
2015-08-29T12:37:31.859339+00:00 app[web.1]: Content-Type: text/html;
2015-08-29T12:37:31.859340+00:00 app[web.1]:  charset=UTF-8
2015-08-29T12:37:31.859341+00:00 app[web.1]: Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
2015-08-29T12:37:31.859343+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-08-29T12:37:31.859367+00:00 app[web.1]: <html>
2015-08-29T12:37:31.859369+00:00 app[web.1]:   <body>
2015-08-29T12:37:31.859370+00:00 app[web.1]:     <h1>Sample App</h1>
2015-08-29T12:37:31.859371+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-08-29T12:37:31.859374+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-08-29T12:37:31.859373+00:00 app[web.1]: <p>Hi asaf ch,</p>
2015-08-29T12:37:31.859377+00:00 app[web.1]: Welcome to the Sample App! Click on the link below to activate your account:
2015-08-29T12:37:31.859378+00:00 app[web.1]: </p>
2015-08-29T12:37:31.859381+00:00 app[web.1]: <a href="http://nameless-depths-7391.herokuapp.com/account_activations/puYr8iDaYEhA7AVzZFccQw/edit?email=asaf.chelouche%40gmail.com">Activate</a>
2015-08-29T12:37:31.859375+00:00 app[web.1]: <p>
2015-08-29T12:37:31.859382+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-08-29T12:37:31.859379+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-08-29T12:37:31.859383+00:00 app[web.1]:   </body>
2015-08-29T12:37:31.859385+00:00 app[web.1]: </html>
2015-08-29T12:37:31.859386+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-08-29T12:37:31.859388+00:00 app[web.1]: ----==_mimepart_55e1a78bc83df_d3ff9ffe09e8858677--
2015-08-29T12:37:31.859390+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-08-29T12:37:31.860566+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-08-29T12:37:31.859500+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 365ms (ActiveRecord: 6.0ms)
2015-08-29T12:37:31.860568+00:00 app[web.1]: Net::SMTPFatalError (550 Unauthenticated senders not allowed
2015-08-29T12:37:31.860570+00:00 app[web.1]: ):
2015-08-29T12:37:31.860571+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/models/user.rb:52:in `send_activation_email'
2015-08-29T12:37:31.860572+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/users_controller.rb:29:in `create'
2015-08-29T12:37:31.860573+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-08-29T12:37:31.969481+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered static_pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (1.6ms)
2015-08-29T12:37:31.860574+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-08-29T12:37:31.963918+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 182.118.44.84 at 2015-08-29 12:37:31 +0000
2015-08-29T12:37:31.975420+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 9ms (Views: 8.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
2015-08-29T12:37:31.864062+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/users" host=nameless-depths-7391.herokuapp.com request_id=5e45ca7b-7cfc-4937-8308-af0dd6e635b0 fwd="79.176.4.149" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=374ms status=500 bytes=1714
2015-08-29T12:37:34.597947+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/application-fabce92ad63641b6fba3541208baa5fa6f9123fbc2a6ff53755cfa33c82906f3.css" host=nameless-depths-7391.herokuapp.com request_id=17b5c268-5738-407f-8008-35fa2fc87d13 fwd="182.118.44.84" dyno=web.1 connect=14ms service=71ms status=200 bytes=116024
2015-08-29T12:37:37.760187+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/application-f26e3b60020a4a03b7dd1f85013a27fd2f7f7e11c4e044cd603969a46ab6935a.js" host=nameless-depths-7391.herokuapp.com request_id=87574b64-9450-4d2c-a4ea-c2d02827fef9 fwd="182.118.44.84" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=25ms status=200 bytes=151483
```

Comment: You're not supposed to run tests in production environment. Better inspect the cause of the error through `heroku logs`.

Comment: @D-side, I just edited the original post with heroku's log. Took me some time to properly format the little bugger.
Plus, I ran all test in development environment on heroku\local machine.

Comment: When going through heroku's log, it is clear that in fact, the user was successfully created and saved in the db, and that a confirmation email was rendered, but was soon followed by an ERROR 500.
Also, for some reason, it seems that the SQL query that inserts the user's details to the db lacks some fields that were implemented in chapter 11 - also odd, since the git repo was pushed to heroku without errors.

Comment: There seems to be an error while sending mail i.e; in your `user.rb` in ` send_activation_email` method.
Can help more if you paste your user model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### SMTP server setup on Heroku

I completed the tutorial a while ago. Still have my code. Maybe I can help.

From the error:

> Net::SMTPFatalError (550 Unauthenticated senders not allowed
>   2015-08-29T12:37:31.860570+00:00 app[web.1]: ):

**Production.rb**

It seems your SMTP server is not set up. If you're following the tutorial  Sendgrid is your mail server. Here's the SMTP setup from production.rb from the tutorial. Is this what you have?

```
  # Ignore bad email addresses and do not raise email delivery errors.
  # Set this to true and configure the email server for immediate delivery to raise delivery errors.
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp

  host = 'your-heroku-app-9999.herokuapp.com'
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: host }
  ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
    :address        => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
    :port           => '587',
    :authentication => :plain,
    :user_name      => ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'],
    :password       => ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'],
    :domain         => 'heroku.com',
    :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }
```

**Mail server environment variables on Heroku**

These 2 environment variables need to be setup in your app's [Heroku setup](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/smtp). Given the error you're seeing I suspect this is the problem. The username and password must also be setup on [Sendgrid](https://addons.heroku.com/sendgrid) itself.

```
ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'],
ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'],
```

I think you're close to having this work, you just need to complete the mail server setup. Please let me know if this helps or if you have questions.

P.S. It could be a REGEX issue, but I would make confirm the setup is solid before diving into the model debugging.

Comment: The problem was indeed that the 2 Sendgrid environment variables weren't defined. In order to define them, had to do some mumbo-jumbo in heroku, and then ran the command `$ heroku addons:create send grid:starter`, as stated in the tutorial. Everything works perfectly, thanks a bunch!